executable name gets argument with windowsVerbatimArguments = true @ node-child-process-spawn (Win32)
Is the following a bug or a feature ?
The second part of the executable C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe will become the first argument of the command spawned with
require('child_process').spawn( 'C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe',
 ['"a b.txt"'], { windowsVerbatimArguments:true } )

i.e. Notepad++ tries to open a file with path <working directory>"\Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
Wrapping the executable in quotes
require('child_process').spawn( '"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"',
 ['"a b.txt"'], { windowsVerbatimArguments:true } )

will result in ENOENT for the executable.
As workaround one can use PROGRA~1 for "Program Files"
require('child_process').spawn( 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe',
['"a b.txt"'], { windowsVerbatimArguments:true } )

